# Custom Variables in custom FormType

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Got some question about passing custom variables to a custom FormType

I have a custom FormType named KontoType:

I pass some custom variables to it and this works like as expected, if i override the method buildForm and dump the passed $options array, the mandant exists and is a entity.

But how the heck can i now pass this custom variable to the function getChoices() which loads the choices based on the mandant in this custom FormType?

Even if i did reset the $options in the override buildForm function like $options['choices'] = $this->getChoices($options['mandant']) the select box is empty if i render this form.

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\Entity\Core\Finanzen\Konto;
use App\Entity\Core\Organisation\Mandant;
use App\Services\LocaleService;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class KontoType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    private $manager;
    /**
     * @var TranslatorInterface
     */
    private $translator;
    /**
     * @var LocaleService
     */
    private $localeService;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager, TranslatorInterface $translator, LocaleService $localeService)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->localeService = $localeService;

    }

    private function getChoices(Mandant $mandant=null)
    {
        return $this->manager->getRepository(Konto::class)->findBuchbar(true, $mandant);
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'label' => 'konto.name',
            'help' => 'konto.help',
            'choices' => null,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'bs-select',
                'aria-hidden' => 'true',
                'ref' => 'input',
                'multiple' => false,
                'tabindex' => 1,
                'data-live-search' => true,
                'data-size' => 6
            ),
            'choice_label' => function ($choiceValue, $key, $value) {
                return $choiceValue->getKonto()." ".$this->localeService->doTranslate($choiceValue);
            },
            'choice_value' => function(Konto $konto = null) {
                return $konto ? $konto->getId() : '' ;
            },
            'required' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'empty_data' => null,
            'label_attr' => array(
                'class' => 'control-label'
            ),
            'placeholder' => 'message.bitte wählen',
            'mandant' => null
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $options['choices'] = $this->getChoices($options['mandant']);
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }


    public function getParent() {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does **getChoices** return anything when you call it with a mandant != null ?

Comment: Yes, it will ...

I did implement now the getChoices() function one stage earlier (where the kontotype was called) and pass directly the choices to the KontoType FormType instead of the mandant to get all mandant related choices.

With this approach it works